# How to find the process listening to the localhost on OSX?

Tags: php, macos, http

In my Mac(10.11.5), I find a strange php server is listening to my localhost:

```
$ curl -i localhost

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 10:05:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/5.6.23
Content-Location: index.html.en
Vary: negotiate
TCN: choice
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Jun 2007 18:53:14 GMT
ETag: "2d-432a5e4a73a80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

But I can't find any php process:

```
$ ps -ef | grep php

  501   724   500   0  6:06PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep php
```

And any suspicious process listening port 80:

```
$ lsof -i:80

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    526 Sona  202u  IPv4 0x9de3b88faf523ff9      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49823->72-165-119-59.dia.static.qwest.net:http (CLOSED)
Google    526 Sona  219u  IPv4 0x9de3b88faf521c19      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49827->72-165-119-17.dia.static.qwest.net:http (CLOSED)
Google    526 Sona  226u  IPv4 0x9de3b88faf510e09      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49808->pixel.quantserve.com:http (CLOSED)
Google    526 Sona  236u  IPv4 0x9de3b88faf523701      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49824->72-165-119-59.dia.static.qwest.net:http (CLOSED)
Google    526 Sona  237u  IPv4 0x9de3b88faf522e09      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49825->72-165-119-59.dia.static.qwest.net:http (CLOSED)
Google    526 Sona  238u  IPv4 0x9de3b88faf522511      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49826->72-165-119-59.dia.static.qwest.net:http (CLOSED)
Google    526 Sona  239u  IPv4 0x9de3b88faf53ee09      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49828->72-165-119-17.dia.static.qwest.net:http (CLOSED)
Google    526 Sona  240u  IPv4 0x9de3b88faf53f701      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49829->72-165-119-17.dia.static.qwest.net:http (CLOSED)
QQ        640 Sona   11u  IPv4 0x9de3b88f96e3fff9      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49717->123.151.10.189:http (ESTABLISHED)
QQ        640 Sona   13u  IPv4 0x9de3b88f96e3fff9      0t0  TCP sayakiss-mbp.lan:49717->123.151.10.189:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

My question:

1. How to find the process listening to localhost?
2. How to find the file which returns by php?(As you see, php returns something contains `It works!`, so there must be a file contains that text...)

EDIT:

After adding sudo with `lsof`, it gives more:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :80

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd      75 root    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     242 _www    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     456 _www    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     458 _www    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     459 _www    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     460 _www    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     461 _www    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     462 _www    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     463 _www    4u  IPv6 0x9de3b88f918c1379      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

...

the ramain is the same as the `lsof` without sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the built in Apache web server that comes pre-installed with OSX

Comment: But the OSX of my friend doesn't have that... Could you please give any reference about that?

Comment: Maybe they disabled it...?  You can disable it like so:

    `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

Comment: What happens if I disabled it? I think OS X deploy that HTTP server for some specific reasons...

Comment: The only reason is so the user can start crafting websites easier without setting it up initially... You won't break anything by disabling it. I do, and then install my own setup and configuration for multiple vhosts, separate from the built in one, under my user space so it all gets backed up nicely...